# How can I make the Eclipse Oomph information browser visible?

Tags: ubuntu-22.04, oomph

I am on Ubuntu 22.04 latest with Wayland  with a stock standard latest Eclipse committer edition. I am trying to use Oomph, but find that most of the information is unreadable, due to fly-outs selecting specific colors or the ordering of panes.

[image: A black details panel for Oomph]

I have changed theme and detail views on the OS and Eclipse level and pinned the colors for various dialogue types to now avail.

Before I file a bug, I would like to know if anyone has seen this effect. A bug DB search did not turn up any results.

Answer (score 0):

This is due [Eclipse playing poorly with Wayland](https://github.com/eclipse-platform/eclipse.platform.swt/issues/158).

```bash
export GDK_BACKEND=x11
```

before invoking Eclipse turns x11 back on. Here things work ok.

Here is [the documentation of the `GDK_BACKEND` environment variable](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/wayland#GTK). It hints the Wayland renderer to use the [Wayland implementation](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/wayland#XWayland) old [`X11`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System) system.